# Importing React Component from outside directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import '../public/components/NavBar';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <NavBar />
      );
  };
};

export default App;
```

Simple enough. Why am I getting the following compile error?

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/App.js

C:\Users\martin\Documents\Web Projects\ReactApp\app\src\App.js
  10:9  error  'NavBar' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

**NavBar**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class NavBar extends Component {
  handleClick () {
    alert('Hello world!');
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="{this.handleClick}">
                Yeet Club
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript imports need `from` and a name:

```
import NavBar from '../public/components/NavBar';
```

Comment: I get this ``Error in ./public/components/NavBar.js
Module parse failed: C:\Users\martin\Documents\Web Projects\ReactApp\app\public\components\NavBar.js Unexpected token (10:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:2)
 @ ./src/App.js 16:14-52``

Comment: I included the NavBar code above. I still believe the problem is in importing the Component and the not the Component code. This Component works fine when it's included in the src/ folder...